# libgdx- changing the sprite texture with animation

Tags: java, animation, libgdx, sprite

I am using the animation class to make a simple animation, with only 2 frames.
With animation, i can get the index, or texture region at the current time.

```
if (!animation.isAnimationFinished(time))
    time += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
else
    time = 0;
```

But the problem is, that I can't load any texture, its width and height must be a power of 2, so i got a big 1024x1024 texture, that has the 2 images.
With sprite.setTexture() i can only put a Texture, but animation.getframe returns a texture region.

Is there a way to change the sprite texture with an animation?

Also

```
 sprite.setTexture(animation.getKeyFrame(time).getTexture());
```

Does not work.

This works

```
sprite = new Sprite(animation.getKeyFrame(time));
```

But I don't think is the best idea... I think is slow can can make bugs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You usually use **TextureRegion** for sprites. The method that you are looking for is [TextureRegion#setRegion](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/TextureRegion.html#setRegion%28com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion%29) (Sprite extends TextureRegion).

Like this:

```
sprite.setRegion(animation.getKeyFrame(time));
```